# Creating ROS Package with Hokuyo_node catkin

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i am new to ROS
In the tutorials, a package was created using the following command
roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp

If i want my package to have a Hokuyo_node do i have to include all of the dependencies of the Hokuyo_node

Or Can I just do
roscreate-pkg example std_msgs rospy roscpp Hokuyo_node

will the dependencies of Hokuyo_node automatically be added?

I noticed when i miss-spelled Hokuyo_node roscreate-pkg did not give any errors...

Is possible to play with the Hokuyo node if you dont currently have a LIDAR?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54447/creating-ros-package-with-hokuyo_node-catkin/) by [Sentinal_Bias](https://answers.ros.org/users/4120/sentinal_bias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 418 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A package's dependencies should automatically be added when you specify it as a dependency.

The dependency is just a name as you might only create the dependency later. A warning might make sense here to avoid spelling mistakes. You could file a ticket to request that.

I'm not sure, what you want with a hokuyo_node without a Hokuyo. You can start it, but it should immediately give you an error that there is no sensor.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2